# Bootstrap Menu in MasterPage does not work in content/child Pages inside a Directory

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

There is Bootstrap menu in MasterPage , which it works perfectly in pages are in root directory, while pages in a directory does not populate the dropdown menu.

> 

```
http://localhost:3739/ServicePortal/Default.aspx (menu dropdown works
> perfectly)
```

while

> `http://localhost:3739/ServicePortal/RegisteredUserPage/DataForm.aspx (menu drop down does not render/work)`

Master Page Bootstrap menu code is given below:

```
<div class="container">  

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-orange" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">O.S.L</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HomeHyperLink" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <%--<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink10" NavigateUrl="" Text="Services" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></asp:HyperLink>--%> 
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Education Services"/></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Health Services"/></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink3" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Bank Services"/></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink4" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Hotels/Restaurents"/></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink5" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Wedding Halls"/></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink6" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Shops"/></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink7" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Add Services"/></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink8" NavigateUrl="#" Text="Contact us"/></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink9" NavigateUrl="#" Text="About us"/></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hylink" NavigateUrl="~\Registration.aspx" Text="Register"/></li>

           <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> <asp:Label ID="lab_loginStatus" runat="server" Text="Sign In"></asp:Label><strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width:250px">
                <div class="loginfrm">
                    <!-- Login form here -->
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbx_SignInName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control txtfocus-orange" placeholder="Sign In Name or Email"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbx_SignInPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control txtfocus-orange" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox_SignInRememberMe" Text="Remember me" runat="server" />
                         <asp:Button ID="btn_SignIn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-orange pull-right" Text="Sign In" OnClick="btn_SignIn_Click" CausesValidation="false"/> 
                    </div>

                   <%-- <div class="horizentalDivider"></div>
                    <h6><asp:Label ID="lab_NotRegYet" runat="server" Text="Not Registered yet?"></asp:Label></h6>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="link_SignUp" runat="server" Text="Register Now"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Signout" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-orange pull-right" Text="Sign Out" onClick="btn_Signout_Click" Visible="false" CausesValidation="false"/> 
                </div>
            </div>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

please help me in such regards

Comment: Where are your bootstrap files located and how have you referenced them in the master page?

Comment: '<link href="CSS/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />' similary Javascript files are at bottom of MasterPage '  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
     <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
     <script src="JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="JavaScript/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>'

Comment: Bootstrap files are in : **CSS/Bootstrap.min.css** while Javascript files are in **Javascript/jquery-2.1.0**  and  **Javascript/bootstrap.min**

Answer (score 1):

try using `ResolveUrl()` in src

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Common/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js") %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the links you provided in the comment I believe you need to add tildes and slashes to the beginning of your links in order to indicate that those folders are in the root of the site. Otherwise the browser is looking for them in the subfolders where your pages are. Here's what it should look like:

```
<link href="~/CSS/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->  
<script src="~/JavaScript/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="~/JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/JavaScript/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/JavaScript/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: You have given me nice hint, main problem is the bootstrap files path references, the above which you have given the solution i have tried but still it does not work, i have added all the references again in http://localhost:3739/ServicePortal/RegisteredUserPage/DataForm.aspx i-e Dataform.aspx , now it works fine, i think is not the right solution what u say?

Comment: @KhuramJan If the bootstrap menu is on the master page, you should place your script references on the master page. Open up your browser, navigate to that page. See if the scripts/CSS got loaded properly. What Orilux is saying is that you need to use root relative paths rather than just plain relative.

Comment: @KhuramJan, I updated the example to use "~" which should resolve the problem. The Visual Studio web server is running your app in a virtual directory, which is causing the problem with the relative paths.